# matrix structures obtainable by multiplication by unitary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition

Out of "Numerical Linear Algebra" by Trefethen and Bau:

> Suppose we have $3\times 3$ matrices and wish to introduce zeroes by left- and/or right-multiplications by unitary matrices $Q_j$ such as Householder reflectors or Givens rotations. Consider the following matrix structures:
>   $$
> (a)\begin{bmatrix}
> \times & \times & 0\\
> 0 & \times & \times\\
> 0 & 0 & \times\\
> \end{bmatrix}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (b)\begin{bmatrix}
> \times & \times & 0\\
> \times & 0 & \times\\
> 0 & \times & \times\\
> \end{bmatrix}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (c)\begin{bmatrix}
> \times & \times & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & \times\\
> 0 & 0 & \times\\
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>
> (where $\times$ "represents an entry that is not necessarily zero")
>
> For each one, decide which of the following situations olds and justify your claim
>
> (i) Can be obtained by a sequence of left-multiplications by matrices $Q_j$
>
> (ii) Not (i), but can be obtained by a sequence of left- and right-multiplication by matrices $Q_j$
>
> (iii) Cannot be obtained by any sequence of left- and right-multiplications by matrices $Q_j$.

Not sure how to argue, here, and not sure how $Q_j$'s being unitary factors in.

Some help would be hot.

Comment: Does $x$ mean "nonzero-entry here" or does it means "one single special value here!"
Can we assume, we start with general full matrices?

Comment: $x$ " represents an entry that is not necessarily zero". I'll edit my post and make $\times$  out of them. I guess we start with a matrix where all entries are $\times$, i.e. "not necessarily zero".

Answer (score -2):

*Hints.*

(a) Can every rank-1 matrix be reduced to this form?

(b) Handle the first column by Householder reflection. Then try to handle the $2\times2$ submatrix at the top right corner by singular value decomposition. Note that in such a decomposition $USV^\ast$, the unitary matrices $U,V$ may have determinants $-1$. How do you remedy for this?

(c) What is the rank of a matrix in this pattern?

Comment: Hi could you give a more detailed answer please?

Comment: @JustANoob, this site is a place where people encourage and persuade you to think.